# InputStream doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, upload, odbc

I'm new to jsp and I'm trying to create a simple page where the user uploads a photo to the database.

I used a upload.jsp page:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload to Database Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>File Upload to Database Demo</h1>
        <form method="post" action="uploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Portrait Photo: </td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="photo" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And a java class to do the job:

```
package classes.servlets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)    // upload file's size up to 16MB
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // database connection settings
  static final String ODBC_DRIVER = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
  static final String DSN = "jdbc:odbc:PMRteste";
  static final String USER = "root";
  static final String PWD = "1234";


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets values of text fields
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        Connection _conexao = null;

        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }



        //Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client

        try {
                    try {
                try {
                    // connects to the database
                    //DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                    Class.forName(ODBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileUploadDBServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FileUploadDBServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FileUploadDBServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
            _conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(DSN, USER, PWD);

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
            //System.out.append("INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)");
            PreparedStatement statement = _conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);


            if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBinaryStream(3, inputStream);
                //System.out.println("entra aqui");
            }
            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (_conexao != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    _conexao.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

But I always get the error message:  [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.14]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters

I've checked the connection with the database and everything works fine (I can add a Name and a surname in the database).

(The message.jsp only displays a message to the user if the photo was successfully updated or not)

Can you help me? :)

Comment: But inputStream is not null, i've checked (the program goes to the if (inputStream !=null).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but has to go first...

**DO NOT SHARE NON-STATIC MEMBER VARIABLES IN SERVLETS! (I'm looking at you `_conexao`)**

The application server is totally allowed to create 1 instance of this class to serve all requests; if a request arrives while another one is being processed the `_conexao` field wll get overwritten and unpredictable behaviour will occur (spurious exceptions, leaked connections and who knows what elese). Fortunately this can be remedied easilly in your code, just make `_conexao` a local variable of `doPost()`.

---

*Attempt to actually answer:* This may be caused by the `BufferedReader`-related code that consumes the `InputStream`, so setting it to the `PreparedStatement` provides no data. Did you try to ommit this code? Moreover you are closing the `BufferedReader` (`in.close()`) which I believe also closes the underlying resources, i.e. the `InputStream`.

---

And yet another suggestion, irrelevant to the question: I'd use the MySQL driver, instead of the ODBC, unless there is a really good reason.

Sorry for the rant, I'm open to conversation should you need more help!
Good luck with this!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will modify the variable _conexao.
Actually the Bufferreader was an attempt to print the inputStream, just to see what was going on... The original code has no BufferReader and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok with the `BufferedReader`. Did you try the DB insertion code from command line? Using a `FileInputStream` for example? Just to make sure that this stuff works (e.g. that the ODBC-JDBC bridge can handle the `InputStream` correctly in this case). Also, I guess the debugging experiment with the `BufferedReader` shows that you actually *do* receive the file correctly?

Comment: Good idea! I will try the FileInputStream directly (with the file path).
The experiment just showed a bunch of characters (My idea was to put that into mySQL directly... But it didn't work).

Comment: Yes, you should expect that. `BufferedReader` is for text streams, it will translate the binary input to characters (e.g. UTF-8). But it shows that the uploaded "thing" has data, so *I guess* it is OK. Let's see what happens with the cmd line experiment...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the ODBC-JDBC bridge. When I used the MySQL driver it worked fine!

Thanks for the hint Nikos!